# Pymongo Mongoclient connection issue

Tags: python, django, mongodb, pymongo

I have enabled the authentication of MongoDB from its config file and added one user with readWriteAnyDatabase role. Below is the query:

```
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "username",
    pwd: "password",
    roles: [ { role: "readWriteAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]
  }
)
```

I am trying to authenticate to MongoDB with pymongo on my local system but getting the below error:
I am using the below configurations:
**pymongo==3.5.**
**python 3.6.8**
**Django==1.11.7**
**MongoDB version v4.2.0**

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7fb6c2b776a8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/akash/Documents/Python/project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/akash/Documents/Python/project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 147, in inner_run
    handler = self.get_handler(*args, **options)
  File "/home/akash/Documents/Python/project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/runserver.py", line 28, in get_handler
    handler = super(Command, self).get_handler(*args, **options)
  File "/home/akash/Documents/Python/project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 68, in get_handler
    return get_internal_wsgi_application()
  File "/home/akash/Documents/Python/project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 47, in get_internal_wsgi_application
    return import_string(app_path)
  File "/home/akash/Documents/Python/project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 20, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "/home/akash/Documents/Python/project/env/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/akash/Documents/Python/project/Web/project/project/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/home/akash/Documents/Python/project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
    return WSGIHandler()
  File "/home/akash/Documents/Python/project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 151, in __init__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/home/akash/Documents/Python/project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 82, in load_middleware
    mw_instance = middleware(handler)
  File "/home/akash/Documents/Python/project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/middleware.py", line 15, in __init__
    engine = import_module(settings.SESSION_ENGINE)
  File "/home/akash/Documents/Python/project/env/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/akash/Documents/Python/project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mongo_sessions/session.py", line 8, in <module>
    from mongo_sessions import settings
  File "/home/akash/Documents/Python/project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mongo_sessions/settings.py", line 52, in <module>
    MONGO_SESSIONS_INDEXES = DB_COLLECTION.index_information()
  File "/home/akash/Documents/Python/project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 1765, in index_information
    cursor = self.list_indexes()
  File "/home/akash/Documents/Python/project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 1719, in list_indexes
    codec_options)["cursor"]
  File "/home/akash/Documents/Python/project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 232, in _command
    collation=collation)
  File "/home/akash/Documents/Python/project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 477, in command
    collation=collation)
  File "/home/akash/Documents/Python/Datafornprojectix/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/network.py", line 116, in command
    parse_write_concern_error=parse_write_concern_error)
  File "/home/akash/Documents/Python/project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/helpers.py", line 210, in _check_command_response
    raise OperationFailure(msg % errmsg, code, response)
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: command listIndexes requires authentication
```

Below is my connection string:

```
  DB_NAME = 'somedb'    
  DATABASE_USERNAME = 'username'    
  DATABASE_PASSWORD = 'password'    
  DATABASE_HOST = '127.0.0.1'    
  DATABASE_PORT = '27017'    

  client = MongoClient('mongodb://{0}:{1}@{2}:{3}/?authSource=admin'.format(DATABASE_USERNAME, DATABASE_PASSWORD,
                                                                              DATABASE_HOST, DATABASE_PORT))
  DB = client.DB_NAME
```

or

```
  client = MongoClient('mongodb://username:password@127.0.0.1:27017/?authSource=admin')
  DB = client.DB_NAME
```

Comment: are you sure that your `authSource=admin` is correct ?, here you should put your `Database` not username

Comment: Yes authsource is admin database only

Comment: I mean the authSource should be your database name, see https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/authentication.html

Comment: I have created the user in admin database

Comment: so DB_NAME = 'admin' ?

Comment: Whenever you create a connection string you have to specify that from which database you want to authenticate and here I am authenticating with admin database as I have created a user with readWriteAnyDatabase role in the admin database.

After authenticating I can connect to any database in that MongoDB. For example:
**DB_NAME = 'somedb'**  
**DB = client.DB_NAME**

Answer (score 0):

You have created the user on 'admin' DB but in your connection parameter, you're connecting to 'somedb'. You must switch to admin db and do the authentication or create the user in 'somedb'

Answer (score 0):

If you want your user to have broader permissions, then after running createUser you should then run [updateUser](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.updateUser/). To give access full access to other databases (which I guess you are trying to do) run the command below in the admin database

```
use admin

db.updateUser(
   "username",
   { roles: [ { role: "root", db: "admin" } ] }
)
```